# Linking a record to more than one table record type

Tags: sql, database

In my application a user can post comments against either a post or a reply to a post. This is NOT the same as nested comments as the reply is a different table to the comment. I guess this is very similar to the way in which StackOverflow works.

I'm confused about how to link it though as what would the foreign key be? As normally I'd just put post_id in the comments table but I also need reply_id to link it to the answer IF its linked to that rather than the actual post. Although I guess I'd need both in that instance so to link to the post and the reply on that post although the reply itself is already linked... confusing right?

What's the best way to do this? Thanks

```
POSTS
id
title
content
datetime


REPLIES
id
datetime
content
post_id


COMMENTS
id
datetime
content
post_id
reply_id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways you can do this. One would be to allow COMMENTS.reply_id to be zero, or -1, or some other code that indicates that the comment isn't related to a reply (sorry, I try to avoid NULLs at all costs!). The other way would be to replace the post_id and reply_id columns with two columns as follows:

```
COMMENTS
id
datetime
content
parent_id (could be post_id or reply_id)
parent_type (could be 'post' or 'reply' or something else)
```

There are caveats with both approaches, the chief being how to enforce referential integrity.

Hope this helps. Not exactly 3rd normal form but it will get the job done.

Comment: Yeah I was thinking of doing the first approach of using 0 or -1 but your second approach seems nicer. I'll give it a whirl, thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Reply ID would be the foreign in your Posts table as you will be having multiple replies for a single post. If any of your posts will be deleted then all the corresponding replies need to be removed.So I would say that reply id should remain as a foreign key in your database.

1)Each Post will have multiple replies.
2)Each Reply will have multiple comments.

If any reply is deleted from the REPLIES table then all the corresponding comments should be deleted.So I would suggest you to use comment id as a foreign key for REPLIES table.

```
POSTS
id
title
content
datetime


REPLIES
id
datetime
content
post_id  

REPLYCOMMENTS
id
datetime
content
reply_id

POSTCOMMENTS
id
datetime
content
post_id
```

These tables and relationship should work I guess.

Comment: Yeah it is already in the Posts table. But i mean for the comments!

Comment: For comments you should consider comment id as a foreign key for reply id as comments are something related to REPLIES table.If a reply is deleted then all the corresponding comments should be deleted.

Comment: Comments can also be related to the post and not a reply

Comment: If its the case then comment id should be a foreign key for both POSTS and REPLIES table... Comments for a post and reply are unique...

Comment: A post can have multiple comments and so can a reply so comment id can't be the foreign key.

Comment: Why comment id cannot be a foreign key? 1)Each post can have multiple  comments.(one to many) 2)Each post can have multiple replies.(one to many) 3)Each reply can have multiple comments. (one to many) This relationship is sufficient to have comment id as a foreign key to POSTS table.

Comment: According to your post the Post would only have 1 Comment rather than a post have many comments, hence why the post_id would be in the comment table!

Comment: Yep you are right.. If its the case you can split the Comments table into two tables as REPLYCOMMENTS and POSTCOMMENTS table and have foreign key relationship separately...